# flask не обрабатывает post запросы

Tags: javascript, flask, fetch

Пишу сервер на Flask написал функцию, когда отправляешь туда post запрос с питона, то всё ок, а когда fetch, то flask не обрабатывает информацию, переданную в post запрос.
Как решить?

```python
fetch('tesss',{method:'POST', body: JSON.stringify({name:'test'})})
```

Вот так не работает.

Comment: Что значит не обрабатывает? Не получает запрос, ошибки есть, не отдает ответ?

Comment: Вы уверены, что Вы пишите сервер, а не сервис? Покажите хоть одну строчку кода, которую можно отнести к понятию сервер, я за Вас порадуюсь. [REST же всегда сервисом был](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST). Дважды подумайте, зачем Вы отредактировали обратно.

Comment: 'tesss', А это у вас такой url?

Answer (score 0):

Запрос должен посылаться на определенный url адрес. Например:

```
const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/tesss';
fetch(url,{method:'POST', body: JSON.stringify({name:'test'})});
```